# Как правильно реализовать operator+() при таком объявлении

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Как правильно реализовать оператор для класса:

```
Department operator+=(Course &);
```

Сам класс:

```
using namespace std;

class Student;
class Course;

class Department
{
// overload input output streams
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &, const Department &);
    friend istream &operator>>(istream &, Department &);

private:
    string name;
    long id;

    Course** coursesOfDepartment; // list of pointers course in this department
    Student** studendOfDepartment; // list of pointers studetns of this department
    Student** badStudentsOfDepartment; // list of point students by the course points < 65

public:
    static int departmentsCounter; // count num of elements
    Department();
    // set get block
    void setId(long);
    void setName(string);
    string getName() { return name; }
    long getId() { return id; }

    // overload block 
    Department &operator=(const Department &); // instead copy constructor
    bool operator>(const Department &) const; // check if count of students greater than count of students in another department
    Department operator+=(Course &); // add new course to to the department list
    Department operator+=(Student &); // add new student to to the department list

    ~Department();
};
```

В операторе нужно создать новый объект класса `Course` и добавить его  в массив `Course** coursesOfDepartment`.

Comment: А причём тут `main`, простите?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Судя по всему под этим:

```
Course** coursesOfDepartment; // list of pointers course in this department
Student** studendOfDepartment; // list of pointers studetns of this department
Student** badStudentsOfDepartment; // list of point students by the course points < 65
```

вы подразумеваете динамические массивы соответствующих указателей. В таком случае вам не хватает ещё некоторых данных, а именно - текущей длины каждого из этих массивов.

Тогда алгоритм добавления нового элемента в массив курсов будет следующий:

1. выделить участок памяти под массив курсов длиной = (текущая длина массива курсов +1);
2. переместить все объекты из исходного массива курсов в этот новый массив;
3. освободить участок памяти, который занимал исходный массив;
4. добавить копию нового курса в конец нового массива.

Чтобы не городить весь этот огород с использованием/освобождением памяти проще всего использовать стандартный класс `std::vector`. Тогда ваш код становится очень прост:

```
std::vector<Course> coursesOfDepartment; // list of pointers course in this department
std::vector<Student> studendOfDepartment; // list of pointers studetns of this department
std::vector<Student> badStudentsOfDepartment; // list of point students by the course points < 65
```

А ваш оператор будет таким:

```
Department& Department::operator+=(const Course& course)
{
  courcesOfDepartment.push_back(course);
  return *this;
}
```

**PS:** Лично моё мнение, что `operator+=` в данном случае не подходит по своей семантике. Я бы использовал вместо него функцию:

```
void Department::addCourse(const Course& course)
{
  courcesOfDepartment.push_back(course);
}
```

Comment: @roma, обратите внимание, что я изменил сигнатуру вашего оператора на `Department& operator+=(const Course& course);`. Т.е. аргумент принимаем по константной (!) ссылке - т.к. не планируем его изменять, а возвращаем не новый объект `Department`, а ссылку на текущий.